# How to send message from non web java application to angular application through websocket?

Tags: java, angular, websocket

I am building a web based dashboard using angular to run the automation test of our application and i want to show the logs generated during the test execution in dashboard at real-time. The problem is I'm unable to connect the websocket server in automation code-base with the client in angular dashboard. I googled my problem but only found example where both client and server are web based. Hope someone can point me to right direction to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Basically I'm trying to send the logs generated from test to angular application using websocket.

**Update :**

I found a way to connect to javascript but now I'm getting `Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

Here's my code setup:

WebSocket Server (Test Script):

```
public class TestStepBroadcaster {
ServerSocket sersock;
Socket sock;
OutputStream ostream;
BufferedWriter bw1;
PrintWriter pwrite;

     public TestStepBroadcaster()  {
           try {
                sersock = new ServerSocket(3002);
                sock = sersock.accept();
                ostream = sock.getOutputStream();
             } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
             }
           pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);
     }
   // method that we call from client code to send message
     public void broadcast(String message) throws IOException {
           pwrite.println(message);
           pwrite.flush();
     }

     public void close() throws IOException {
         bw1.close();
         ostream.close();
         sock.close();
         sersock.close();
     }
}
```

WebSocket Client (Angular App):

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
     title = 'my-dream-app';
     websocet: WebSocket;

     constructor(private channel: ChannelService) {
        console.log('from app constructor')
       // this.websocet = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');
        this.websocet = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:3002');

        this.websocet.onmessage = function (event) {
            console.log(event.data);
        };
        this.websocet.onopen = function (evt) {
            console.log("onopen.");
        };
        this.websocet.onclose = function (evt) {
         console.log("onclose.");
        };
        this.websocet.onerror = function (evt) {
         console.log("Error!");
      };
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.channel.data.set('isLoggedIn', false);
  }
}
```

So now my question is , What may be the reason for Connection Refused Issue?

Thanks.

Comment: If possible, share your stackblitz version of what you have tried?

Comment: A websocket,a s its name indicates, isn't just a socket. A client connects over HTTP to a web server, and they decide to switch to a TCP-based communication. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: ok but can point me where i'm missing?